# How can I find the Nexus 5 option from device definitions?

Tags: android, nexus-5

I can't find the Nexus 5 option from device definitions of Android Virtual Device Manager.

Just list my development environment: LG Nexus 5 smartphone
Eclipse plus Android Developer Tools: Build v 22.3.0-887826

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create an AVD that acts like the Nexus 5? Or do you want to develop with your physical Nexus 5 phone?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides AVD's that mimic their devices from time to time. You can check for AVD updates, but until then, you will need to select parameters that best describe your device. Since the AVD varies from a real device in many ways - like no Google Play, missing some sensors - you may have to use your real device.

Here are the tech specs: http://www.google.com/nexus/5/

And you can create a new AVD from this: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate over to the USB driver directory, which on my machine was: **C:\Users\Xxxxxxxxx\android-sdk\extras\google\usa_driver**

In that directory, edit file android_winusb.inf in both the x86 and amd64 sections and insert one line:

```
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1&MI_01
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to develop with your Nexus 5 phone, you do not need to use the Android Virtual Device Manager at all. As the name suggests, the AVD Manager is for creating **virtual** devices. This is certainly a useful tool because you don't have to go out and buy multiple devices just for testing.

In order to use your own phone, you should follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. The exact details depend on which OS you are developing from.

Comment: Thank for your help. Actually I have a physical Nexus 5 phone. However I'd like to test the application in virtual devices before I deployment the application to the phone.